# Getting radio input from selection in table

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get my code to open a page that displays a picture of the model and displays information. the code uses a csv file that populates the table. I cant seem to figure out how to get my radio button to pass data based on selection. I'm trying to find the selected row and display the data on another page basically. any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Choose One</h1>

<form action="index.php" method="post">

        <label for="Type">Package Type</label>
        <select name="Type">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        <option value="a">apple</option>
        <option value="b">google</option>
        <option value="c">oneplus</option>
        <option value="d">Samsung</option>
        </select>
        <input type="Submit" >

</form>
<?php

echo "<html><body><table border = '1'>\n\n";
echo "<form action='stock.php' method='post' name='stock'>";
echo "<th>Item</th><th>Manufacturer</th><th>Model</th><th>Price</th>";

$myfile = fopen("phones.csv", "r");
$ind=0;
$ind++;
while (($dataarray = fgetcsv($myfile)) !== false) 
{

echo "<tr><td>"."<input type = 'radio' name='manufacturer' id=manufacturer 
value=$dataarray[$ind]>"."</td>";
foreach ($dataarray as $cell) 
{
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
$ind = 0;

}

fclose($myfile);
echo "\n</table>


<input type='submit'>

</form></body></html>";


$ind = 0;
?>




</body>
</html>
```

Start of stock.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <form action="index.php" method="get" name="stock">
 </form>
 <php?

 if(isset($_get[manufacturer]))
 {
   $value=$_get[manufacturer];
 }

 ?>
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
 </html>
```

This is a snip of the csv file:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what your specific issue is but basically when the form is submitted you should be able to get the selected radio button value from `$_POST["manufacturer"]`

Comment: My only guess is that your problem might be related to the fact that this page has two separate forms...are you hoping to submit the manufacturer value at the same time as the Type value, perhaps? If so then you need one form containing all the fields. But again, your description of the problem was very vague so it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little new at this. a little more information: the radio button will be on a the beginning of each row in my table. based on user selection the table contains information about phones and they companies., the selected radio button will return this information on a separate page and display a picture. How can I get the selected row from radio button choice and display the data on the second page named stock.php. when i use the post method the data is not returned on the other page.

Comment: Well it _should_ work based on what you've shown...but only if you submit the second form. Please show us the code of stock.php so we can check if there are any problems there

Comment: Thanks for thee help @ADyson. i posted the csv file. and the stock.php code as well

Comment: `if(isset($_get[manufacturer])) {  $value=$_get[manufacturer]; }` should be `if(isset($_POST["manufacturer"])) {  $value=$_POST["manufacturer"]; }` ... because 1) your form submits a POST not a GET (also please refer back to the example in my very first comment!), 2) PHP is case-sensitive so `$_get` doesn't even exist anyway (and therefore submitting a GET would also have failed), and 3) you forgot the quote marks around `manufacturer`, which means PHP will be trying to interpret that as a constant. You should see errors about these problems...if you don't, then turn on error reporting!.

Comment: Oh and `<php?` should be `<?php` ...so maybe it's not even executing the PHP at all... Details matter in programming, even (or especially!) the small ones, so please pay attention to them and always double-check your work for typos, and if you're unsure or have a problem, check against examples you can find online of how to do common tasks such as reading data from a form submission - there are so many examples available that there's really no reason to get something like this as wrong as you did.

Comment: Thank you I got it fixed. I should have seen the typos. really appreciate the help!